# Sound card not detected 16.04 Dell Inspiron 15 7579 (Dummy Output)

Tags: 16.04, sound, soundcard

Running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron 15 7579

I have tried several things to have sound in my laptop with no success, below is a list of the most relevant attempts.

1. Reinstalling `linux-sound-base`, `alsa-base`, etc. as mentioned in
   [Ubuntu 14.04 does not recognize sound card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463958/ubuntu-14-04-does-not-recognize-sound-card)
   and [Sound card not detecting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471433/sound-card-not-detecting).
2. Sound Output Troubleshooting https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting.
3. Upgrading the kernel module to 4.6 as mentioned in [Sound card not detected (16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846059/sound-card-not-detected-16-04)
   and following the referred instructions in
   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1551880.

After trying 2. above I know the following:

The system **does not** recognizes my sound card.
Running `sudo aplay -l` gives `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`

I do have the sound modules installed 
`find /lib/modules/`uname -r`| grep snd` shows a large list of items.

The sound card is recognized by my hardware.
`lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"` outputs

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0743
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at d1128000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at d1100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
```

I wanted to try the manual installation mentioned in that Sound Troubleshooting link but I don't know the name of my sound card driver in order to run `sudo modprobe snd-[NAME OF YOUR SOUNDCARD'S DRIVER]`.

This is what my sound configuration panel looks like, always trying to play sound through that *dummy object*.

[image: Dummy Output]

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron 15-5578 and it uses the Realtek ALC3253 Audio Codec which is the same as in your notebook.

I've got the sound working like this:

Open the relevant config file for editing, for example by running this command:

```
sudoedit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

and add this line:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic probe_mask=0x103
```

(or modify the line if you already have an entry that starts with `options snd-hda-intel`)

Save the file and then run these commands

```
killall pulseaudio
sudo alsa force-reload
pulseaudio -D
```

Comment: Didn't work for me with `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic probe_mask=0x103` nor `options snd-hda-intel model=headset-mic probe_mask=0x21`. The 0x21 came from trial and error mentioned in [my similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1143257/307091).